# XSLT: how to print a value if none of checked values match with the value I want to print?

Tags: xml, xslt, if-statement, foreach

XML:

```
<person>
    <callingName>Name3</callingName>
    <givenNames>
        <givenName>Name1</givenName>
        <givenName>Name2</givenName>
        <givenName></givenName>
    </givenNames>
</person>
<person>
    <callingName></callingName>
    <givenNames>
        <givenName>Name1</givenName>
        <givenName>Name2</givenName>
        <givenName></givenName>
    </givenNames>
</person>
```

I need to check all the 'givenName' elements if their value matches with the 'callingName' element inside the 'person' element. Empty values shouldn't be counted as a match. If none of the values match, the value of 'callingName' element should be printed. How can I do it?

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
<xsl:if test="callingName != givenNames/givenName[normalize-space()]">
    <xsl:for-each select="givenNames/givenName[normalize-space()]">
        <xsl:element name="callingname">
            <xsl:value-of select="callingName"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
```

Problem is that everytime values don't match, it prints the value of 'callingName' element. How can I check if all of the values don't match, value is printed only once?

Answer (score 1):

> If none of the values match, the value of 'callingName' element should
>   be printed.

Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="people/person[string(callingName) and not(callingName=givenNames/givenName)]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="callingName" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to a **well-formed(!) input**:

```
<people>
    <person>
        <callingName>Name3</callingName>
        <givenNames>
            <givenName>Name1</givenName>
            <givenName>Name2</givenName>
            <givenName></givenName>
        </givenNames>
    </person>
    <person>
        <callingName></callingName>
        <givenNames>
            <givenName>Name1</givenName>
            <givenName>Name2</givenName>
            <givenName></givenName>
        </givenNames>
    </person>
</people>
```

will **result** in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <callingName>Name3</callingName>
</output>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following XSLT matches each `person` and includes the `callingName` in the output if there is no matching `givenName`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="person">
    <xsl:if test="not(givenNames/givenName[text() = ../../callingName])">
        <xsl:copy-of select="callingName"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<callingName>Name3</callingName>
<callingName/>
```